# How to plot the progress of an optimization?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scipy, scipy-optimize

Is there a way to plot the progressive value of a function being optimized with scipy.optimize's differential evolution? In the following the plotting part doesn't work:

```
from scipy.optimize import rosen, differential_evolution
bounds = [(0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5)]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, disp=False)
print(result.x, result.fun)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x, f = zip(*result)
plt.plot(x, f)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I originally answered this question thinking you wanted the *path* taken by the optimizer, not the value during optimization. I've updated the answer so that it shows both, but you're probably only interested in the second plot.

The object returned by `differential_evolution` does not contain the path towards the result, nor the values along the way. However, you can use the `callback` argument to provide a [callback function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)) that gets called on each iteration. That callback can then record the progress.

For example:

```
progress = []
progress_err = []

def cb(x, convergence):
    progress.append(x)
    progress_val.append(rosen(x))

bounds = [(0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5), (0, 5)]
result = differential_evolution(rosen, bounds, disp=False, callback=cb)

progress = np.array(progress)
progress_val = np.array(progress_val)
```

Since you seem to want to optimize the 5D Rosenbrock function, visualization of the entire path becomes a bit tricky. If I opt to visualize just the first two coordinates (+ the value, which is what you're actually asking about), i.e.

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1)
ax.plot(progress[:, 0], progress[:, 1])
ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax.plot(progress_val)
plt.show()
```

I get

[image: A path and value during optimization]

The value, which is what I just realized you're actually asking about, is the bottom plot. If you don't need the path itself, disregard anything in the code having to do with `progress`.

Of course, your result may look different because our random seeds, and therefore our paths towards the optimum, are different.

Comment: That's most helpful - appreciated. However, I meant the value of the objective function (Rosenbrock in this case) rather than the coordinates. Now, `x` in the callback is the coordinate array and I can't see any way to extract the value of `func` from differential_evolution. Does this mean that the only solution is to plug the extracted coordinates into the objective function ?

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly called the function values "the error". In case of the Rosenbrock function, that happens to be true, but that's just by coincidence. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Why is it bad to have to plug the coordinates into the objective function? This is cheap compared to what the optimizer is doing anyway.